# How to reference context variable in Switch in API Connect?

Tags: api-gateway, apiconnect

in APIC 2018, suppose I set a variable like this in a gatewayScript

```
let apim = require('apim')
apim.setvariable('isSuccess', true)
```

now  I want to reference this variable in switch policy such that flow changes based on this boolean value, how to do that?